# RegexReplace and RangeToTable issue

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I am writing to seek your help with finding a solution to fix the following regex which I am using on the output of the RangeToTable() function. The RangeToTable() function outputs the HTML Code that has several types of values among which we also have columns with the date. The date is coming out in a format we dot need i.e. with the name of the day and timestamp and timezone. We just need the date and nothing else.

To achieve that, I came up with an additional column where I am using the RegexReplace() function to find and replace any timestamps ending with time zones, however, when I do that it matches everything from the first instance to the last one in the whole code which is replacing the whole content instead of replacing just the set of timestamps with timezones.

If I manually enter the line breaks (pressing enter on the keyboard after each HTML closing tag) in the code and add a global (\g) switch, it works well, however,  I need to achieve this on the raw form of code as this will be automated using formulas.

RegEx I am using:

```
\s(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].*\)/g
```

Code Sample:

```
<table cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px solid grey;">
<tr><th style="background-color:#DDDDDD; border: 1px solid grey;">Hire Date</th>
<th style="background-color:#DDDDDD; border: 1px solid grey;">Last Work Date</th>
<th style="background-color:#DDDDDD; border: 1px solid grey;">Last Paid Date</th></tr><tr>Sun Jun 16 2013 14:30:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)</td><td style="border: 1px solid grey;"></td><td style="border: 1px solid grey;"></td></tr><tr><td style="border: 1px solid grey;">Thu May 31 2018 14:30:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)</td><td style="border: 1px solid grey;"></td><td style="border: 1px solid grey;"></td></tr><tr><td style="border: 1px solid grey;">Sun Nov 26 2017 13:30:00 GMT-0500 (EST)</td><td style="border: 1px solid grey;"></td><td style="border: 1px solid grey;"></td></tr><tr><td style="border: 1px solid grey;">Sun Jun 10 2018 14:30:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)</td><td style="border: 1px solid grey;"></td><td style="border: 1px solid grey;"></td></tr><tr><td style="border: 1px solid grey;">Sat Jul 08 2017 14:30:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)</td><td style="border: 1px solid grey;"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid grey;"></td></tr></table>
```

Please help me find a suitable fix.

Best Regards,
Syed H

Answer (score 1):

Try this (inside the //g):

```
[^<>]+(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-9][0-9][^<>]+
```

This isolates just the date strings because they are inside an HTML tag (after ">" and before "<").

Comment: Dear Aurora, Thank you for your helpful response. It is, however, stripping away the whole date. I need to have the date and remove the day (Sun/Mon...) and timestamp and time zone. Please help

Comment: Dear Aurora, I am currently using \s(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-9][0-9][^<>]+ and managed to rip the timestamp and timezone. However, I am still struggling to remove the day (Name) as well. Please help

Comment: You have a regex that you say is working to isolate the stuff after your content of interest, like " 13:30:00 GMT-0500 (EST)" for removal.  Coming up with a regex that will isolate the stuff before your content of interest, like "Sun ", seems like it would be more challenging, in terms of avoiding false positives elsewhere in your HTML.  Perhaps you should work to isolate the entire string containing your content of interest like "Sun Nov 26 2017 13:30:00 GMT-0500 (EST)", and also isolate your content of interest like "Nov 26 2017", and replace the former with the latter?

Comment: Dear Aurora, thank you for your response. If the replacement is possible, I would love to implement it. Can you please help with your expert advice.